# what is the available emulator to test android automotive app ( not android auto )

Tags: android

I am developing car launcher for infotainment system (not Android Auto) using AOSP (Android Open Source Project).

How can I test that application?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to emulate Android Automotive at the moment. As you can see [here](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-android-automotive-emulator-sdk/), there's rumours of Google working on an emulator, but no news so far:

> Two commits in the AOSP source code indicate the release of the emulator. One states the tag for Android Automotive image folders has been created, and the other mentions a test for “oc-car-m1″ emulator images. This likely stands for “Android Oreo Maintenance Release 1″, possibly being Android 8.1. If this is the case, then it’s likely we may see an emulator around the time Android 8.1 launches.

Comment: @ miguelarc ,is it possible to emulate the Android Automotive with Android-9.0.0_r8

Comment: It is now possible to run android automotive with an emulator. I've managed to do it (android_cts_8.1_r7), but it's still in an early state. You can try checking out and building it yourself, but I don't know in what state it is in that particular build. I advise you to build and emulate it on linux, and try checking if the particular build as some sort of "emulator"/"emulation" folder. That's should have all the emulation related stuff.